# EM on product of multinomials

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, gibbs, expectation-maximization

I have the following conditional density:

$$
P(x | \theta, \pi) = \prod_{i=1}^I \prod_{j=1}^J t_{ij}! \prod_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{x_{ijk}!}(\sum_{l=1}^L \theta_{il} \pi_{jkl})^{x_{ijk}}
$$

Here, $x$ is the data (observed). $\theta$ and $\pi$ are latent parameters that are unobserved. Finally, $t_{ij}$ is a constant that is calculated from the data. My overall goal is to infer the latent parameters ($\theta$ and $\pi$) given the data ($x$).

Basically, $P(x | \theta, \pi)$ is a product of I*J multinomials. The parameters of each multinomial are controlled by $\theta$ and $\pi$. I'll briefly describe these variables. First, $\theta_i$ is a probability vector of length L. In other words, for all $i$, we have:

$$
\sum_{l=1}^L \theta_{il} = 1
$$

The $\pi$ variables are indicator variables. For a given $j$ and $k$, they tell you which $\theta_{il}$'s to include in the sum. Intuitively, each multinomial is built from $K$ total parts. For each part $k$, we iterate through all possible $\theta_{il}$ and select which ones to include.

There are a few simple constraints on the $\pi$ variables. For a given $j$ and $l$, there is only one $k$ for which $\pi_{jkl}$ is non-zero. It follows that:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{l=1}^L \theta_{il} \pi_{jkl} = 1
$$

I hope this explanation is ok. Anyway, my goal is to infer the latent parameters $\theta$ and $\pi$. I was hoping I could do this with EM. My problem is that given $\pi$ and $x$, I don't know how to update the $\theta$ variables. I tried maximizing $P(x | \theta, \pi)$ over $\theta$, but I am running into trouble because the $\theta_{il}$'s are all dependent (because they must sum to 1). This makes calculating the derivative rather difficult. I was hoping that someone could give me advice or point me in the right direction.

Also, if people can recommend other solutions, I would really appreciate it. Right now, I am looking into sampling from the posterior distribution of the parameters (given the data), but I need to do more reading to fully understand how this works.

I can place a Dirichlet prior on $\theta$ and a discrete uniform prior on $\pi$, if it helps. Thanks!